# Использование интерфейсов и абстрактных классов

Tags: php

Что правильнее и логичнее использовать в приведенном ниже примере, реализацию интерфейса или наследование класса? Из определения я не совсем усвоил что будет правильно

```
class car {

}

abstract class param { 
    public function move($length) {}
}

interface param {
    public function move($length) {}
}
```

Что если нам надо будет в `param` добавить ещё один параметр который поддерживают не все `car`?

Например изменится вот так

```
abstract class param { 
    public function move($length) {}
    public function fly($height) {}
}

interface param {
    public function move($length) {}
    public function fly($height) {}
}
```

Comment: Абстрактный класс `обязует **определять** некоторые` методы, а Интерфейс `обязует **использовать** только некоторые` методы. Ключевые слова: определять и использовать

Comment: @Peresada то есть абстрактный класс обязуется определять некоторые входящие в его набор методы и наследник может их использовать и переопределять либо вовсе не использовать никак, а реализация интерфейса позволяет реализовывать только методы входящие в набор интерфейса? Но что тогда правильно сделать в моем примере? Мне всё ещё не понятно..

Comment: @ВладимирАлександров не совсем так. Абстрактный класс используется для расширения функционала, а Интерфейсы - для ограничения функционала. В интерфейсе Вы не можете реализовывать методы, а в абстрактном классе можете (кроме абстрактных методов). В Вашем варианте логичней использовать абстрактный класс Params

Answer (score 2):

Честно говоря я не очень понял что значат `параметры` и как они соотносятся с глаголами типа `move` и `fly`, но если я Вас правильно понял, то Вам нужен расширяющий функционал, а не ограничивающий. (Интерфейс именно ограничивает), и судя по коду, у Вас пока нет необходимости именно в абстрактном классе. Для простого расширения функционала достаточно просто наследовать класс Car

```
class Car {

    public function move(length) {//код}
    public function fly(height) {//код}
}

class Pego extends Car {

    public function dance() {

    }
}

class Reno extends Car {

    public function cryMeAriver() {

    }
}
```

Вообще разницу можно объяснить довольно просто:

Простое наследование: **Расширение**

Абстрактный класс: **Расширение с условиями**

Интерфейс: **Ограничение**